# How do I programmatically show the layers panel?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a map using Open Layers 2. I have the standard LayerSwitcher in the top right of my map, [like in this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/example.html).

How do I set the layers panel to be open by default? The control is added like this:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
```

It adds a div in the top right with an ID of `OpenLayers_Control_MaximizeDiv`, on which I've tried triggering a click, but nothing happens. Even though clicking manually with the mouse does open it. Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var control = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
map.addControl(control);
control.maximizeControl();
```

This is the internal function called when you click the "maximize" button of the control.